# Sort the contents of the input text file and creating a make qemu out of it in c language

Tags: c, sorting, qemu, xv6

I want to do the following:

1. develop c program in such a way that in qemu terminal, executable named sort should be created.
2. when given "sort sample.txt", it should take contents of the sample and sort the text inside it in ascending order.
3. create an output file and dump this output.

I did like this :

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   #define MAX_LEN 100 // Length of each line in input file.

   int main(void)
                 {
    char *strFileName = "C:\Users\sample\xv6-public\data.txt";
    char *strFileSummary = "C:\Users\sample\xv6-public\out.txt";
    char strTempData[MAX_LEN];
    char **strData = NULL; // String List
    int i, j;
    int noOfLines = 0;

    FILE * ptrFileLog = NULL;
    FILE * ptrSummary = NULL;

    if ( (ptrFileLog = fopen(strFileName, "r")) == NULL ) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Error: Could not open %s\n",strFileName);
     return 1;
    }
    if ( (ptrSummary = fopen(strFileSummary, "a")) == NULL ) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Error: Could not open %s\n",strFileSummary);
     return 1;
    }

    // Read and store in a string list.
    while(fgets(strTempData, MAX_LEN, ptrFileLog) != NULL) {
     // Remove the trailing newline character
     if(strchr(strTempData,'\n'))
        strTempData[strlen(strTempData)-1] = '\0';
    strData = (char**)realloc(strData, sizeof(char**)*(noOfLines+1));
    strData[noOfLines] = (char*)calloc(MAX_LEN,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(strData[noOfLines], strTempData);
    noOfLines++;
}
// Sort the array.
for(i= 0; i < (noOfLines - 1); ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < ( noOfLines - i - 1); ++j) {
        if(strcmp(strData[j], strData[j+1]) > 0) {
            strcpy(strTempData, strData[j]);
            strcpy(strData[j], strData[j+1]);
            strcpy(strData[j+1], strTempData);
        }
    }
}
// Write it to outfile. file.
for(i = 0; i < noOfLines; i++)
    fprintf(ptrSummary,"%s\n",strData[i]);
// free each string
for(i = 0; i < noOfLines; i++)
    free(strData[i]);
// free string list.
free(strData);
fclose(ptrFileLog);
fclose(ptrSummary);
return 0;
 }
```

'''

But, how to add it to qemu executables?

Comment: Unrelated, I'd be concerned about how all those file names aren't correct. Back-ticks need to be escaped (with another back-tick). I'm surprised your compilers isn't barking at you about "unknown escape sequence" or some other such warning.

Comment: @WhozCraig "Back-tick" is actually a backslash, a back-tick looks like this: \`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "add to qemu executables". Please, would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: Ya, thank you all for your responses, the thing is that: 1) I am trying to use a **sort** command and add it to the **xv6**- operating system's call 2) I am writing a c code which can be added to xv6-executables in the **_Makefile_**. I finally got what I was asking for. I will post the answer to why I did get formatting issue was that I copy-pasted the question. Apologies for it, I will be posting my answer, please review it and let me know if it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying data around like crazy, even reallocating the strings with `MAX_LENGTH`! that's not necessary at all. How can you forget what pointers are!

```
char* temporary;
for(i= 0; i < (noOfLines - 1); ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < ( noOfLines - i - 1); ++j) {
        if(strcmp(strData[j], strData[j+1]) > 0) {
           temporary=strData[j];
           strData[j]=strData[j+1];
           strData[j+1]=temporary;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't help you with the qemu part, isn't there a way to build it to the required architecture and putting in the `PATH`?

Comment: I am using C code for xv6-operating system to implement **sort** - system call.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I implemented in my xv6-public repository by writing a C code and adding it to the system call. It worked, thanks for your inputs.

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "fcntl.h" // for using file defines
#include "user.h" // for using from strlen


void insertionSort(char *arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   char *key;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
   { 
       key = arr[i]; 
       j = i-1; 
       while (j >= 0 && atoi(arr[j]) > atoi(key)) 
       { 
           arr[j+1] = arr[j]; 
           j = j-1; 
       } 
       arr[j+1] = key; 
   } 
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if(argc != 6){
        printf(2, "sort: enter 5 numbers please.\n");
        exit();
    }

    int i;
    char* nums[5];
    for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        nums[i] = argv[i+1];
    insertionSort(nums, 5);
    printf(2,"proccess id is %d \n", getpid());
    int fd;
    if((fd = open("sorted.txt", O_CREATE | O_WRONLY)) < 0){
      printf(2, "sort: cannot open file");
      exit();
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        if(write(fd, nums[i], strlen(nums[i])) != strlen(nums[i])) {
            printf(2, "sort: write error\n");
            exit();
        }
        if(write(fd, "\n", 1) != 1) {
            printf(2, "sort: write error\n");
            exit();
        }
    }

    exit();
}
```